# why my css is overriden by scss which is even not included

Tags: css, materialize

I was working on materialize css and using this library https://materializecss.com/

I compile the sass and included the css file in my html but when i was trying to do some custom css i found the strange thing.

when i inspect the element i saw chrome is taking css from .scss files that i still dont used in my html.

[image]

while i was only including two css files.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css"  media="screen,projection" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
```

Comment: Chrome is aware of the source map, which links you back to the original .scss file Materialize uses. You need a higher specificity to override that setting.

Comment: how could i do that please help

Comment: Please search for CSS specificity.

Comment: i have even removed the scss file from my system but it still showing same

Comment: Like I said, Chrome is aware of a source map for Materialize.

Comment: thanks for your help i sort that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are chasing a ghost.  The problem is *not* the SCSS, but rather has to do with [CSS Specificity](https://pawelgrzybek.com/css-specificity-explained/) as pointed out in the comments.  Ignore the fact that the rule is coming from `.scss` files, and focus on the CSS specificity.

**Why you see .scss files in the inspector:**
The `materialize.css` file, which you **are** including, includes a reference (called a "source map") to the materialize SCSS files (if you view the materialize.css file, you'll see the sourcemap reference listed at the bottom of the file).  Because of that source map, when you inspect items in your browser's developer console, it actually shows you the *SCSS* line(s) that are applying styles.  This is a good thing, and if you ever develop in SCSS yourself, you'll be very thankful for it.

**The Real Problem:**
The point is, however, that the `materialize.css` styles are taking effect, and your `styles.css` styles *are not having effect*, because of [CSS Specificity](https://pawelgrzybek.com/css-specificity-explained/).

Note in the materialize styles the selector is:

`.side-nav .collapsible-body li a,
 .side-nav .nav.fixed .collapsible-body li a { ...`

These are *specific*.  They are only addressing `a` elements that are within an `li`, that are within `.collapsible-body`, that is within `.side-nav` (in the second selector, there is of course the additional `.nav.fixed` element).

In *your* styles, your padding is being ignored because it contains a more general (aka *Less Specific*) selector:

`.collapsible-body li a { ...`

This is *not specific*.  It is generally addressing any `a` elements that are within an `li` that are within `.collapsible-body`.  These *will not* override styles that have been set more specifically, like the materialize padding style you are attempting to override.

If you want your styles to override the `materialize` styles, you'll need to use styles that are *at least as specific*.  For example:

```
.side-nav .collapsible-body li a,
.side-nav .nav.fixed .collapsible-body li a {
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Hope this helps.  If you are going to continue to work with materialize, or bootstrap, or any other framework, you really would benefit from reading some articles on CSS specificity.